# iOS: Animate color change from left to right

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I want to animate the background color of a `UITableViewCell` from left to right (kinda like a progress bar) and I'm stumped. Is this possible?

**Edit**

Went with the suggestion to add a background view that periodically expands its width, but that is not working. here is the code I have right now:

```
// in viewDidLoad
self.tableView.reloadData()
self.beginWorkout()
...
// beginWorkout
private func beginWorkout() {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)
    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MovementCell
    cell.animateProgressView()
}
...
// MovementCell animateProgressView
func animateProgressView() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(15, animations: {
        self.progressViewWidth.constant = self.screenWidth
    })
}
```

but the animation doesn't execute over time. the `progressViewWidth` constant becomes the screen width immediately.

Comment: what about adding a view in the bottom, set its initial width to zero, and set its background to the color you want, and animate the view's width to increase

Comment: was considering that but was hoping there'd be a way to do it with the color

Comment: also having issues with autolayout animation within the uitableviewcell

Comment: what are the issues?

Comment: it is not working. ha. The animation code is executing all at once.

Comment: added an edit to show the issues @MudOnTire

Comment: `func animateProgressView() {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.progressViewWidth.constant = self.screenWidth
        UIView.animateWithDuration(15, animations: {
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }` try this to animate with constraints

Comment: while it works for me, i will past my solution later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)startProgress:(id)sender {
[self layoutIfNeeded];
self.progressViewWidth.constant = 300;
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
}];
}
```

and this is the expected output ,When I click go:

[image]

Comment: you're right, it worked when i called it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Something about the way I was trying to access the cell outside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` was causing it to not work or something I don't even know.

Comment: I prefer to put all the cell updating related code in the cell's class, it makes the view controller's code more concise and architecture more clear, and view controller's job to pass models or change status of cells

Answer (score 1):

you can do like,

```
UIView * testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320.0f, 100.0f, 320.0f, 200.0f)];


[testView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

[self.view addSubview:testView];  //In your case cell's content view

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.7f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                 animations:^{
                     [testView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 100.0f, 320.0f, 200.0f)];
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

You can change different animation options. For example if you want auto reverse and repeat you can use `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse` as option.

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to behave just like a progress bar, put a UIView (blue background for example) in your cell with the lowest z-order.

Now animate its width relative to the cell width.